# website uses an invalid security certificate

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl, .htaccess, virtual-machines

I have website on `ubuntu` with `apache` server. Domain is from `godaddy`. When I type `example.com` it's running file under SSL (with https). But, for `www.example.com` it's giving me below error.

> www.example.com uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for the following names: someother.com, www.someother.com, someother.com (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)

**What I did?**

I tried to talk with `godaddy`. They suggested me to disable SSL v3 from apache server. Everything is ok from their side.

Then I changed `ssl.conf` file with this: `SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3` according to [this](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/security-patches/disabling-sslv3-for-poodle) documentation. But, still it's giving me the same error.

**configurations**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias www.example.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public_html
   ErrorLog /var/www/example/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/example/error.log
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example-bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: What is the VirtualHost configuration for `https://www.example.com`? Your current configuration is only for `https://example.com`.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen: I don't have it.. What changes do I need to make here to consider that URL as well?

Comment: Where's the DNS pointing for `example.com` versus `www.example.com`?  Is this a shared host or do you control the server?  And what's the output from `apachectl -S`?

Comment: @ShaneMadden: I have control over the server. I fixed it by Tero's solution. Thanks.

Comment: @RonakPatel Ok - FYI, since that was the fix there's another virtual host on 443 that you'll see with `apachectl -S` which got the requests by default because of the missing alias. You might want to verify that that config was intended.  And you should probably mark Tero's answer as "accepted"! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

```
ServerAlias www.example.com
```

in your `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` section.

Comment: oh.. it was really silly mistake. I was trying since last 2 days. Thank you so much.